# Extending association of multiple models with common method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I want to be able to extend multiple associations from the different models with common code, for example from `extending_relation_method` class method. But I can't achieve `self` inside this method to be relation object. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
module ModelMixin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def extending_relation_method
      owner = proxy_association.owner
      # some processing
      self
    end
  end
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelMixin

  def self.test1
    self
  end

  has_many :field_values, as: :owner, autosave: true do
    # works
    define_method :test1 do
      self
    end

    # works
    def test2
      self
    end

    # do not work
    define_method :test3, &(Model.method(:extending_relation_method).unbind.bind(self))
    define_method :test4, &(Model.method(:extending_relation_method).unbind.bind(Model))
  end
end
```

---

UPDATE:

Now I think question can be simplified to finding out the reason and work-around for this behavior:

```
proc1 = Proc.new { self }

def method_for_proc(*args)
  self
end
proc2 = method(:method_for_proc).to_proc

1.instance_exec(&proc1)
#=> 1
# as expected

1.instance_exec(&proc2)
#=> main
# why??
```

Solved original problem by replacing shared method to shared Proc, but I want to understand why this happening.

```
module ModelMixin
  EXTENDING_RELATION_PROC = Proc.new do
    owner = proxy_association.owner
    # some processing
    self
  end
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :field_values, as: :owner, autosave: true do
    # works
    define_method :test, &EXTENDING_RELATION_PROC
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To investigate your issue with procs you can see comments in source code of `to_proc` method here http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-to_proc. So `to_proc` creates new `Proc` not with body of method, but with calling of this method (bounded to `main` in this case).

But I think in your specific case it would be better to write something like:

```
module ModuleMixin
  def extending_relation_method
    # some processing
    self
  end
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :field_values, as: :owner, autosave: true do
    include ModuleMixin
  end
end
```